# WordPress integrating social login not working in PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.1

I am trying to integrate social login in WordPress. I have installed the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/. It is working fine for the PHP version 5.6.31. When I change the PHP version to 7.1.9 it is showing plenty of warnings while clicking on the twitter authentication button.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'cache_control' in E:\wamp64\www\iedecode\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-social-login\hybridauth\Hybrid\thirdparty\OAuth\OAuth1Client.php on line 263
```

Please help.

Comment: you can hide warnings or go to that line (stated in the error) and check what's wrong is happening.remove or comment that and then re-check

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before `$this->http_header[$key] = $value;`:

```
$this->http_header = [];
```